# remove new line from array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I m trying to filtering the filenames from a text file

```
my $fname= "filenames.txt";
open (FPTR,$fname) || die "Can't Open File: $fname\n";
chomp(my @filenames = <FPTR>);
```

The context of the file is like below

```
file1.pl
file2.pl
file3.pl
.
.
.
file100.pl
```

But when i print the @filenames array its like

```
';AR1 = 'file1.pl
';AR2 = 'file2.pl
';AR3 = 'file3.pl
';AR4 = 'file4.pl
.
.
.
.
$VAR100 = 'file100.pl';
```

Even though i add the chomp the new line was not removed from array elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are using Linux to process a file originating from Windows, which puts CR LF at the end of each line. Your `chomp` removes the LF, leaving CR. You can fix that by changing your code like so

```
my $fname = 'filenames.txt';
open my $fptr, '<:crlf', $fname or die qq{Can't open file "$fname" for input: $!};
chomp(my @filenames = <$fptr>);
```

An alternative way would be to replace `chomp` with

```
s/\R\z// for @filenames;
```

or

```
s/\s+\z// for @filenames;
```